# Alsa/Pulse mute audio after a while with network sink on raspbian

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, alsa, pulseaudio, streaming

Here is my setup :

- Raspberry 3 with raspbian, connected to TV (video and sound) and connected to lan with ethernet. (pulseaudio 5.0)
- Arch Linux Laptop and Desktop (Ethernet / Wifi) - (Pulseaudio 10)

What I'm trying to achieve is to be able to stream sound to my "HTPC" Raspberry from any computer in the lan. 
To do so I added

```
load-module module-native-protocol-tcp auth-ip-acl=127.0.0.1;192.168.0.0/24 aut$
load-module module-zeroconf-publish
```

To /etc/pulse/default.pa and installed pulseaudio-module-zeroconf on the raspberry.

Now I can select the Raspberry as an output from the sound settings of both of my computer.
It works well for like 4 or 5 minutes and then the sound stops, and most of the time I don't even get disconnected.

On my computer I get :

```
[pulseaudio] module-tunnel.c: Stream died.
[pulseaudio] sink-input.c: Failed to create sink input: sink is suspended.
```

Nothing on the Raspberry journal and nothing apears with pulseaudio -vvvv either.

I can easily restart the sound by restarting pulseaudio on the rpi or, by using alsamixer to mute and unmute the audio...

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: Any particular reason you are using a raw TCP stream? If that stream dies, because of timeouts or whatever, it dies. Why don't you use something like [RTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real-time_Transport_Protocol) (`module-rtp-send` and `module-rtp-receive`) that is designed to do this kind of thing?

Comment: No particular reason, just easy to setup thanks to zeroconf. I just tried with RTP, it works but same problem with the sound muting after a while...

Comment: That's odd, RTP uses UDP packets and should recover. What are the error messages? Anything putting the RaspPi to sleep for some reason? If you simultanously login into the RaspPi via ssh, do you see anything?

Comment: The rpi is no going to sleep (The TV screen is on and ssh is working good). On the rpi side I have a bunch of

Comment: `D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] module-rtp-recv.c: Updating sample rate
D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] module-rtp-recv.c: wi=105128344 ri=78839002
D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] module-rtp-recv.c: Write index deviates by 26792.94 ms, expected 500.00 ms
D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] module-rtp-recv.c: Estimated target rate: 44086 Hz, using average of 44107 Hz  (α=0.020)
W: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] module-rtp-recv.c: Sample rates too different, not adjusting (44100 vs. 102092).
D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] module-rtp-recv.c: Updated sampling rate to 44100 Hz.
`

Comment: But I don't thin that's relevant. On the sender side I have no error at all.

Comment: I'd say a write index deviation of 26 seconds, whatever that means in detail, is not good. Wild guess: Are the clocks of both machines reasonably synchronized? Whan happens if you synchronize both with `ntpdate` before sending?

Comment: Good guess, time was completly off. Now the deviation doesn't get much bigger than expected. I tried again another time and I noticed that just after the sound stopped, the "Write index deviation" grew to reach seconds and minutes. Not sure what it means. And if I get it working back (muting/unmuting or changinf the sound level with alsamix) the audio lags behind aproximatly as much time.

Comment: So something (possibly different processing speed due to buggy sample rate conversion?) causes samples to collect in a buffer, which causes different write index times, which causes audio lag if it gets going again (because the buffer is not cleared). You can try filing a bug with the Pulseaudio devs, but in my experience they are not that responsive. This will probably need quite a bit of debugging to find the cause.

Comment: Ok so I updated to Pulseaudio 10 from testing, it still doesn't work but the error are a bit different just before it stops.

Comment: D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] sink.c: latency = 21772
D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] sink-input.c: Have to rewind 4 bytes on render memblockq.
D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] source.c: Processing rewind...
D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] sink.c: alsa_output.0.analog-stereo: Found underrun 4 bytes ago (4572 bytes ahead in playback buffer)
D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] sink.c: alsa_output.0.analog-stereo: Found underrun 4 bytes ago (4572 bytes ahead in playback buffer)

Comment: That's quite a different error, now you get underruns instead of samples piles up. Another wild guess: Is your RaspPi overclocked/underclocked/or any other possible reason why the internal timer is out of sync with real time?

Comment: Nothing, just stock Raspbian. I just setup the time and it is the same as my laptop. The last error before the sound stop is `D: [alsa-sink-bcm2835 ALSA] source.c: Processing rewind...`